# Name That ...Name? 8

Tags: riddle, knowledge

In the 3rd century, the kids lost my history in the rocks

My shorter version does what it says on the box

A bird comes in here, you get an infamously loved guy

I also slightly cut through the wood that you buy

Name the Name

Hint 1

> The fourth line refers to the short version of the name as line 2 states

Hint 2

> The first line refers to a famous saint that kids and unfortunately adults still have many misconceptions about. The "in the rocks" is just for a rhyme

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are

> Nicholas / Nick

In the 3rd century, the kids lost my history in the rocks

> (Also hint: *The first line refers to a famous saint that kids and unfortunately adults still have many misconceptions about. The "in the rocks" is just for a rhyme*)
>
>  St. Nicholas was a 3rd-century saint that fits the description.

My shorter version does what it says on the box

> Nick is a... nickname

A bird comes in here, you get an infamously loved guy

> A bird goes in a cage. Nicholas Cage is an actor loved by many

I also slightly cut through the wood that you buy

> A nick is a small cut.

Comment: Correct, but for the second line, think about another word for a shortened form of a name

Comment: @XavierStanton aaaa, got it now

Comment: Darn it! This is embarrassing that I didn't get this haha, great answer @jafe! :D

Comment: (because I saw it and never considered my own name could be an answer)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is right, but the only thing that's coming to me is

> Petra?

In the 3rd century, the kids lost my history in the rocks

> Petra is a city carved into a rock face in Jordan which was lost for hundreds of years.

My shorter version does what it says on the box

> When you get a pet (rock/cat/etc), the box often says you can pet it, and Pet is short form for Petra.

A bird comes in here, you get an infamously loved guy

> No idea.

I also slightly cut through the wood that you buy

> Part of Petra is Petr-, which is the start of petrified, as in petrified wood.

Comment: Unfortunately no

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is

> Rome?

First line:

> During the third century, Rome almost collapsed due to internal conflict and troubles. Maybe 'kids' refers to a newer generation of political and military figures destroying what their predecessors created.

Second line:

> Shorter version of Rome -> Rom. ROM or read only memory is literally read only memory--what it says on the box.

Third line:

> Romeo is a famous (or infamous) literary figure whose name is associated with romance. Romeo and Juliet also references birds a lot.

Fourth line:

> Not really sure, but I'm guessing this has something to do with woodcutting or crafting?

Comment: Nope, but I can see where you are going